# Connect ImportValue and parameter store value

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to connect an exported value from another CF script and a parameter in the parameter store.

I have two CF scripts where Script-A outputs a value as follows,

```
  Purpose:
    Value: !Ref Purpose
    Description: Purpose
    Export:
      Name: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${CustomerName}-Purpose'
```

It also creates a SSM parameter with the customer name.

In the 2nd script, I want to read the "Purpose" and feed it as a value while creating another parameter store entry,

```
  TestVar:
    Type: AWS::SSM::Parameter
    Properties:
      Name: !Sub '/test-var'
      Type: String
      Value: 
        Fn::Sub:
        - 'abc-'
        - !ImportValue '${StackName}-'
        - CustomerName:'{{resolve:ssm:CustomerName:1}}'
        - '-Purpose'
```

But I am not sure what is the correct way to do this.

I know I can import Parameter Store values as a parameter on a CF script, but trying to avoid hard coding keys.

Comment: It would save you a heap of trouble if your first CF template created the required `AWS::SSM::Parameter` in the first place, rather than export an Output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things to note using SSM Store Parameters. EVERY TIME you update the value, the version number increments. There is, currently, NO WAY to tell CFN to just use the latest version of an SSM Stored Parameter. Keep this in mind when using these in your templates.

Okay first off, if you are trying to do this the way your template snip looks, you need to do a !JOIN, not a !SUB, that is, if I am reading what you are trying to do right (need more info, but am giving this a shot anyway).

For what you have above, just do something like:

```
        KeyName: !Join ['',['kp-','{{resolve:ssm:AccountShortName:1}}','-default']]
```

If you are trying to do this in a script block, it would look more like:

```
      "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": 
        configSets: 
          configuration: 
            - InitialSetup
        init: # Initialize cfn
          files: 
            'C:\cfn\scripts\SetupDefaults.json': 
              content: !Sub 
                - | 
                  { 
                    "StackName": "${AWS::StackName}", 
                    "Region": "${AWS::Region}", 
                    "Resource": "WinServer", 
                    "directoryName": "${AccountShortName}.com", 
                    "Joiner": "${AccountShortName}/ad/joiner" 
                  } 
                - AccountShortName: '{{resolve:ssm:AccountShortName:1}}' 
          commands: 
        InitialSetup: # Initial Setup 
          files: 
            'C:\cfn\scripts\Initial-Setup.ps1': 
              source: !Join 
                - '' 
                - - 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/' 
                  - '{{resolve:ssm:binaries-bucket:1}}' 
                  - '/new_web/Initial-Setup.ps1' 
              authentication: S3AccessCreds 
          commands: 
            InitialSetup: 
              command: >- 
                powershell.exe -Command "C:\cfn\scripts\Initial-Setup.ps1" 
              waitAfterCompletion: 0
```

Hope this clears things up a bit. If not, post more details and we may be able to dig a bit more to help.

Thanks!